# How to select one number of one hundred with the same possibility? JS

Tags: javascript

Im building a musicplayer and I want to create the random feature, im using now math.random which is obviously a bad idea, because it can repeat the same number many times, so i need to give to them the same chance but dont have it clear how to do it, now I have an array with three music, so if a click in random one of them should play, if I click again the next one, but never the same song twice, how can I do it?

Comment: It is probably the most common question in technical job interviews. You pick a random song, play it and then remove it from the list. You repeat this process until the list is empty.

Comment: I don't know, have you tried basic approaches like storing the song of the name, then pick another song, if the new song is the same as the previous one, pick again, repeat until you pick a different song?

Answer (score 0):

Although already being answered in comments, here is the javascript code example:

```js
// your playlist length
let playlistLength = 10;
// temporary variables
let src = [], res = [], idx, len;
// fill the 'src' array with numbers from 0 to playlistLength-1
for (idx = 0; idx < playlistLength; idx++) src.push(idx);
// while the 'src' array  has any elements
while (len = src.length) {
  // get random element index in 0 .. src.length-1 range
  idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
  // push the element into the array 'res'
  res.push(src[idx]);
  // remove the element from array 'src'
  src.splice(idx, 1);
}
// here is random sequence of numbers from 0 to playlistLength-1
console.log(res.join(', '));
```